# Preview sql result columns in java

Tags: java, sql

Is there any way for 'previewing' sql select statements?
What I'm trying to do is to get the names of the columns that are returned by a sql statement without actually running the statement?

On application startup i need to know the column names, the problem is that some of the queries can run for awhile.

Comment: Where do you SQL statements come from? If you know the statement you should know the columns.

Comment: Please provide more information. You will not get any help this way.

Comment: The sql statements will come from a config file, now this file can be changed by the user at anytime. So the idea is to try and find a way so that is will adapt to the users needs

Comment: If you have the statement as string you could parse it for the columns names.

Comment: Parsing the query can be a option, but that if the query has calculations in then parsing it can lead to problems.

Comment: Just extract the part between `SELECT` and `FROM` and seperate it by `,`.

Comment: Would work for basic queries, but what if the query looked like this. select min(delay) as min, average(delay) as average, max(delay) as max from

Comment: Depends on what you want. If it's `delay`, I admit this could become a little complicated ;-)

Comment: That is the problem I'm currently facing, if the queries all execute on application startup then the load time can be extremely long.

Comment: The thing is if I was in control of what queries will eventually be executed then this would be an easy task,

Comment: Maybe some existing SQL Parser library might help you. Quick googling showed that there seem to be a few.

Comment: Looking at a couple of libs now, will post back if i find a reliable one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention your DBMS, but the following works with the Postgres and Oracle JDBC drivers. I didn't test any other.

```
// the statement is only prepared, not executed!
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from foo");

ResultSetMetaData metaData = pstmt.getMetaData();
for (int i=1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
{
  System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html%20%22ResultSetMetadata) may help

You still have to execute the query to get the meta data, but you may be able to alter add a restriction to the where clause which means it returns zero rows very quickly. For example you could append `and 1 = 0` to the where clause.

The DBMS still has to do all the query parsing that it would normally do - it just means that the execution should hopefully fail very quickly